# Mathematical Induction problem

Tags: induction

Can somebody help me with these questions? I can't seem to get started...

Having $P(n) : n^2 + 5n + 1\text{ is even}$.

a) Demonstrate that if $P(k)$ is True to some $k$ natural, then $P(k + 1)$ is also true.

b) Considering the Principle of Complete Induction, can you say that $P(n)$ is true for all natural numbers?

c) Demonstrate that $P(n)$ is False for all n natural.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a) Let $P(n)$ be the assertion that $n^2+5n+1$ is even. We show that **if** $P(k)$ is true for a particular $k$, then $P(k+1)$ is true.

Suppose that $k^2+5k+1$ is even. Note that 
$$(k+1)^2+5(k+1)+1=k^2+2k+1+5k+5+1=(k^2+5k+1)+(2k+6).\tag{1}$$
By the induction assumption, $k^2+5k+1$ is even. But $2k+6$ is even, and if we add an even number to an even number, the result is even. This completes the proof of the induction step.

b) The Principle of Mathematical Induction says that if (i) $P(1)$ is true and (ii) whenever $P(k)$ is true, $P(k+1)$ is true, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n\ge 1$.

We have proved (ii). But we must also verify (i). And notice that when $n=1$, we have $n^2+5n+1=7$, and $7$ is **odd**. So (i) fails, and therefore the induction "proof" fails.

c) We will show that in fact $n^2+5n+1$ is **odd** for all $n\ge 1$. Let $P^\ast(n)$ be the assertion that $n^2+5n+1$ is odd.

It is easy to verify that $P^\ast(1)$ is true, we just verified it above.

Now let us show that if $P^\ast(k)$ holds, then $P^\ast(k+1)$ holds. We use the calculation in (1). There we concluded that
$$(k+1)^2+5(k+1)+1=(k^2+5k+1)+(2k+6).$$
By the induction assumption, $k^2+5k+1$ is odd. But $2k+6$ is even, and an odd plus an even is odd, so $(k+1)^2+5(k+1)+1$ is odd. This completes the proof of the induction step.

**Remark:** Basically the only point of this exercise is to remind you that in an induction argument, you must show two things: that $P(1)$ holds, and that whenever $P(k)$ holds, $P(k+1)$ must hold. I actally don't quite see the point, since students almost never forget to verify that $P(1)$ holds.

Comment: Okay, @AndréNicolas, i think this is the third question we both have answered within seconds in two days...can you stop having better answers than me....I'm trying to get rep here...  :)

Comment: Our answers have a very similar structure. I am just more long-winded.

Comment: long winded = thorough...

Comment: Strongly disagree on your last sentence. My students are in the habit of writing "P(1) true" with no justification.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: If they are writing this then they are *remembering* that they need to check that $P(1)$ is true!  (And it is a rare induction proof where the base case is actually nontrivial to check...)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Yes they are remembering but are they understanding? I could set this proposition above to prove and I can see many of them write $P(1)$ true and move on...

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: You're right that many students have trouble understanding the logic of induction.  I agree that it would be interesting to ask students to first check the inductive step and then ask them to prove or disprove the statement for all $n$.  My point is that "remembering the base case" cannot be the precise locus of the problem, because in my experience as well as Andre's, the students almost never simply forget to include the base case.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Assume $P(k)$ is even.  Now, for $P(k+1)$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\ P(k+1) &=(k+1)^2+5(k+1)+1 \\
&=k^2+2k+1+5k+5+1 \\
&=k^2+5k+1+2k+5+1 \\
&=2m+2k+6 \text{ (why?)} \\
&=2(m+k+3)
\end{align}$$
Thus $P(k+1)$ is even.

However, 
for #3, 
$$n^2+5n=n(n+5)$$
And since $n$ and $n+5$ are of different parity, $n^2+5n$ is even which means it can be represented as $2p$ for some integer $p$
Thus, $$n^2+5n+1=2p+1$$
What does that mean??

I left the complete induction for you...

Answer (score 1):

First, if you let n = 1 then you get P(n) = 7 which is not even. So you are never going to show it is true for all natural numbers.  If it were true that if P(n) is even for some n, then yes P(n+1) would be even. To see that P(n+1) =  (n+1)<sup>2</sup> +5(n+1) + 1 =$n^2$ +2n + 1 + 5n + 5 + 1 = ($n^2$ + 5n + 1) + (2n + 6).  We assumed first term is even, and clearly the second term is.

But if you assume P(n) is odd for some n, then the above analysis shows that P(n+1) is also odd. So this demonstrates P(n) is odd for n ≥ 1, which includes all the natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need a starting point and the induction argument to get the induction going. But hey:

$$n_2+5n+1=n(n+1)+4n+1.$$

Now $n(n+1)$ is even because it's a product of an odd number and an even number, and obviously $4n$ is even making the whole thing odd.